# VSCode setting to disable git status colors in editor gutter

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the setting variable to turn this off

or if you know why Prettier - Javascript does format the code but some lines are still marked in color like here

I only have Prettier-eslint installed in command line so not sure what else can VSCode trigger

[image: Color next to line numbers]

Comment: Hmm I have the problem that this lines prevent me from setting breakpoints in this part of the code. WTF?? I want to set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 19):

Those are [gutter indicators](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_gutter-indicators) that Vscode adds to files within a git repository.  I don't see any way to get rid of them - other than staging or committing the changes.

You can change their colors within settings.json so you could change them to the same color as the editor background to hide them.  For example,

```
 "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "editorGutter.addedBackground": "#333",
  "editorGutter.deletedBackground": "#333",
  "editorGutter.modifiedBackground": "#333",
  "editor.background": "#333",
 }
```

Comment: oh yea? that's great but I hate it :))
I know how to remove it, you turn of git management completely in VScode,

Comment: Just set the color to transparent: `#0000`. Turning off git support completely is not a good solution unless you don't care about any git features

Comment: @Mark is there a way to change the colors of those git-related indicators on the minimap as well? Particularly the "deleted" type, because having them show as red interferes with the red indicators from eslint errors, which is undesirable

Comment: Nvm I found it on Alex's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43973209/772985 - `"editorOverviewRuler.deletedForeground": "#0000"` - initially tried that but didn't realize I had to actually close VS Code (whole window) and reopen for it to take effect!

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the help of @Mark he helped me figure out it's a git options in Visual studio code that show diff in your file (added and removed lines)

Tu turn it off,  Go to Settings and find git.enabled setting and set it to false

Comment: This doesn't just hide the gutter colors in editor as the OP asked, this turn off all the GIT management of VsCode. Just go to Settings and search for "Scm Diff Decorations" and set to none.