# How do I get git changes to show in explorer in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How it's currently showing:

[image: How its currently showing]

How I'd like it to be

[image: How I'd like it to be]

Previously, it was like this by default. Now, I'm unable to get it to work as such. What are the settings I have to change to enable this?

Comment: stupid question : that directory *is* a git repository, right ? if you open a terminal, go to your `lib/` directory and run `git status`, you do see an output ?

Comment: Check that you didn't accidentally [disabled gitDecoration.* settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43969277/2745495).

Comment: @LeGEC Yep. And that didn't show anything useful. Anyhow, I've solved the issue. Apparently, git doesn't work well with symlinks. I had symlinked my project to my home directory and it didn't show. When I opened the original path folder, all was well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that git doesn't play well with symlinks. I'd setup the symlinks from a different partition to my current partition so as to be able to setup workspaces in different distros, but that doesn't work, rip.
Opening the folder from its actual path resolves the issue.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me crazy for a while now. Sometimes it would work and sometimes it would not work and I couldn't figure out what was going on. Turns out I was loading some projects into vscode from a symlink. When I load the same projects from their actual folder, the git changes show up in explorer in vscode.

Comment: @JohnSmith Same, lol. Glad to help.