# How can I change the style of the thick bar on the left in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I want to change the style of my Visual Studio Code Editor to look like this: (with a thick bar on the left):

[image: thick-bar-editor-color]

Comment: Research this setting: `SCM: Diff Decorations`.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the answer! That's true, it's only needed to set "scm.diffDecorations" in Visual Studio Code settings from "all" to "gutter". Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969277/how-can-you-disable-gutter-indicators-in-vs-code
And useful documentation about the meaning of colors for gutter indicators in Visual Studio Code is here:
https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/versioncontrol/#gutter-indicators

Comment: In addition to that, it's important to restart the editor to apply changes, and Diff Decorations only apply to folders that only are git repositories.

Comment: @LuisAngelRodríguez If you found the answer please put an answer in your own post so other will know too, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, it's only needed to set "scm.diffDecorations" in Visual Studio Code settings from "all" to "gutter". Reference:
[How can you disable Gutter Indicators in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969277/how-can-you-disable-gutter-indicators-in-vs-code)

[example-of-how-to-set-scm.diffDecorations-in-vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwJtL.png)

And useful documentation about the meaning of colors for gutter indicators in Visual Studio Code is here: https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/versioncontrol/#gutter-indicators

Answer (score 0):

Since Local History was added in March, the settings for the SCM gutter decorations changed a tad bit. Bellow shows what the new decorations look like.

[image]

```
    /** @file "settings.json" */

    {
        "scm.diffDecorationsGutterAction": "diff",
        "scm.diffDecorationsGutterVisibility": "always",
        "scm.diffDecorationsGutterWidth": 4,
        "scm.diffDecorationsGutterPattern": {
            "added": true,
            "modified": true
        },
    }
```