# How to change the style of deleted git line in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

as shown in the above picture

1. On the far left, in git, the style of the prompt icon of the deleted line is too small, and it is easy to be ignored. Is it possible to modify the style?
2. Can the color of the prompt on the rightmost scroll bar be modified? Because this color is consistent with the grammatical error prompt, it cannot be distinguished

Comment: mostly a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69097815/11107541 I think

Comment: thanks, some settings of the link are helpful for me, but how to change the red triangle color?