# How can I remove these git status colors on the background of my vscode scroll bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I want the background of my scrolling bar on vscode to be transparent. It has this colors according to the git status of each line inside the file. For example, yellow for changed, green to staged, etc

Comment: I don't have them so you must have an extension that does this, what does it look like in vsc-insiders without extensions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Settings > Features > Source Control > Diff Decorations Gutter Visibility

Here's an example:
[How can you disable Gutter Indicators in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969277/how-can-you-disable-gutter-indicators-in-vs-code)

Comment: This setting didn't work for me, but going to `Diff Decorations` and selecting `gutter`/`minimap`/`none` instead of `all` worked.